# C++ Token Pasting Operator not concatenating __LINE__ in pre-processor definition

Tags: c++, token-pasting-operator

I have defined the following pre-processor directive:

```cpp
#define TIMER(name) ::my_app::Timer timer##__LINE__(name)
```

Using as follows:

```cpp
TIMER("first");
TIMER("second");
```

I get an error stating that the second usage redefines `timer__LINE__`.

```
::my_app::Timer timer__LINE__("first");
::my_app::Timer timer__LINE__("second");
```

What I actually want is a definition of timer with the source code line number appened, e.g.:

```cpp
::my_app::Timer timer1("first");
::my_app::Timer timer2("second");
```

If it's any use, my clang version details:

```sh
❯ /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang --version
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

I see examples of where [this syntax is used and works](https://github.com/TheCherno/Hazel/blob/master/Hazel/src/Hazel/Debug/Instrumentor.h#L222) (`::Hazel::InstrumentationTimer timer##__LINE__(fixedName.Data)`). Why is the token pasting operator not working as I'd expect in my scenario?

Comment: Does it really work there?

Comment: I assume so - there are a reasonable number of contributors and I suspect significantly more using it (it's from a YouTube series). But the original is MSVC, so perhaps compiler implementation differences cause it to work there?

Comment: Thanks for the linked question - solved perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to defer the concatenation after the evaluation of `__LINE__`:

```c
#define CONCAT(a,b) a b
#define PASTE(a,b) a##b
#define TIMER(name) ::my_app::Timer CONCAT(PASTE,(timer,__LINE__)) (name)
```

Alternatively, name the variable like the timer name using the stringify-operator:

```c
#define TIMER(name) ::my_app::Timer timer##name (#name)

TIMER(first)
TIMER(second)
```

results in

```c
::my_app::Timer timerfirst ("first")
::my_app::Timer timersecond ("second")
```

Comment: hmm this is a rather confusing way to defer concatenation, it is usually done like presented in the dupe.